# Session/Query Context Info in logs for Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: azure-synapse

Does Azure SQL Data Warehouse provide a feature to allow the context of the query to be logged?  I have read that the JDBC API Specification refers to this kind of database feature as "Client Info".  Oracle provides a built-in procedure dbms_application_info.set_client_info to set Client Info, and Oracle stores the Client Info in a column in Oracle's v$session table.  Teradata calls their feature QueryBand and stores the information in their query log (DBQL).

My basic use case is for the dynamic SQL being generated by an application to include the context related to who (i.e., user, department) is responsible for the resulting query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that with [query labels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-label).